# Building IEnumerable in loop

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, myob

**Classes:**

```
public class CalculateDiscountsFees
  {

    public IEnumerable<CalculateDiscountsFeesItem> Items { get; set; }
  }

public class CalculateDiscountsFeesItem
{

    public int RequestID { get; set; }


    public CalculateDiscountsFeesSale Sale { get; set; }


    public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }
}

public class CalculateDiscountsFeesSale
{
    public Guid UID { get; set; }

    public CalculateDiscountsFeesSaleType Type { get; set; }
}
```

These are the classes that are in a sdk that I need to use. I need to build CalculateDiscountsFees and then pass it back to the sdk. However I am having trouble doing this. The way I would like to do it is in a loop, create a CalculateDiscountsFeesItem and then try to add it to the to the CalculateDiscountsFees. This won't work because ienumerable doesn't have an add.

I have tried creating Extension module to create my own add but have failed to get it to work.

Here is the code that I would like to work in a ideal world. Hopefully this will give you some sort of idea of what im trying to do.

```
       Dim fees As New CalculateDiscountsFees
       Dim sale = New CalculateDiscountsFeesSale
       Dim feesitem = New CalculateDiscountsFeesItem
       Dim id = List.Item(0).UID
       sale.UID = id
       sale.Type = Version2.Sale.CalculateDiscountsFeesSaleType.Invoice
       feesitem.RequestID = 1
       feesitem.PaymentDate = Now()
       feesitem.Sale = sale
       fees.Items.Add( feesitem)
       Dim feeResult = CalculateDiscountsFeesSvc.Execute(companyFile, fees,     credentials)
```

Wondering how I can build CalculateDiscountFees. I have tried creating a list of CalculateDiscountFeesItems but am then not able to get it to CalculateDiscountFees type.

Would appreciate any suggestions. Have now spent a full working day on it with no progress.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a list of `CalculateDiscountsFeesItem`s, then take that list and assign it to the instance of `CalculateDiscountsFees`'s `Items` property, like this:

```
Dim fees As New CalculateDiscountsFees
Dim listOfCalculateDiscountsFeesItem As New List(Of CalculateDiscountsFeesItem)

Dim sale As New CalculateDiscountsFeesSale()
Dim id = List.Item(0).UID
sale.UID = id
sale.Type = Version2.Sale.CalculateDiscountsFeesSaleType.Invoice

Dim feesItem  As New CalculateDiscountsFeesItem()
feesitem.RequestID = 1
feesitem.PaymentDate = Now()
feesitem.Sale = sale

listOfCalculateDiscountFeesItem.Add(feesItem)

... 
Repeat above for as many fees items as you need in the list
...
```

Now you can take your `List(Of CalculateDiscountsFeesItem)` and assign it to the `fees.Items` property, like this:

```
fees.Items = listOfCalculateDiscountFeesItem.AsEnumerable()
```

Comment: That work! Thank you very much. 

You solved it so quickly i feel like an idiot but just so glad to finally have it working!

Thanks again!